# How to get neural network parameter after training?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am using matlab's neural network for classification.
I want to know how can I store network parameters such as: **epoches, time, mse**, etc. In a matrix after training?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

When calling [train](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html?searchHighlight=train), the second returned argument is the [training record](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/post-training-analysis-network-validation.html?searchHighlight=Training%20record), this contains the epoches, time and other info about the training. e.g.

```
[net,tr] = train(net,data,target);
tr.epoch
tr.time
```

For the [mse](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mse.html?searchHighlight=mse), given test data `data`, target data `target` and neural network `net`:

```
%run inputs through network 
result = net(data);
%get the error
error = result - target;
%calculate mse
mse(error)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the network parameters in a cell array. Please find more details in the following link: http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html